# How do you make a text editor (gedit) apply colors to code?

Tags: text, editor, syntax-highlighting, gedit

Usually, when I'm using a text editor like gedit, in order to make it apply a color scheme to the code all I have to do is save it with the appropriate extension and the code color changes. Recently, saving as .html or .java hasn't been doing the trick. Is there any way to force the text editor to recognize this and apply the color?

Comment: For me it works (I use Ubuntu, you?). Please check if spec files for html and java syntax are in place, here: /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/

Comment: What version of gedit are you running?

Answer (score 1):

On the menu bar, I have to select *View > Highlight Mode > Sources > Java* to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting should be automatic based on mime type. If it isn't happening automatically for simple types like .html or .java then you have a problem, but it is hard to know where with the information you included. check /usr/share/mime/packages and /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/ for content.